# Graphics display messed up since upgrade to 14.10 from 14.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I upgraded to 14.10 from 14.04 and now my grphics are very messed up. with Xorg nouveau and with the nvidia 340.58 driver I have the same issue with the display being far to big for the screen so that I cannot even see the login prompt. I have tried removing aand re-installing the nvidia-340 driver (340.58) but that has not fixed the issue. The only way I can get to a useable display is to press cntrl+alt+F2 then cntrl+alt+F7 but that display is only 1280 * 1024. Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling mesa as well.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Then reinstall the driver of your choice, nouveau or nvidia.